# Fixed width right bar and resizable content

Tags: html, css, resize

I tried to get two divs next to eachother. The right one has a fixed width, but the left one has to be able to resize. I tried multiple ways, but none fit all my requirements:

1. Right one has fixed width
2. Parent div has height of largest child (wraps its childs)
3. Left one has to resize
4. Html structure has to in this order (reason at bottom):

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="variable_width"></div>
    <div class="fixed_width"></div>
</div>
```

I tried **absolute positioning** the right div and adding a margin on the left one and it achieved all requirements, except that the **parent div doesn't wrap the largest child** (as expected)
 http://jsfiddle.net/0fxL71xL/3/

```
.container{max-width:400px;position:relative;}
.variable_width{margin-right:100px;}
.fixed_width{width:100px; position:absolute;right:0;top:0;}
```

I also tried using **inline-block** and max-width but then the divs don't align at the top, and I don't know how to handle the whitespace issue. Most important, it **does not make the left div resize**: http://jsfiddle.net/0fxL71xL/4/

```
.container{max-width:400px;}

.variable_width{max-width:290px; display:inline-block;}
.fixed_width{width:100px; display:inline-block;}
```

I also tried a **float** right on the right div, but it didn't come near what I wanted.
The closest I got was changing the order in html and using float:right on the div that has to go right, but in this case I can't use an @media query to have it display below the left div at a certain moment.

EDIT:While paulie_d's answer fixes it, I would prefer something that has a large browser support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more searching I came across this interesting page which sums some techniques to achieve exactly what I wanted. It gives the most complete answer.

http://clubmate.fi/100-percent-height-columns-fixed-width-sidebar-pure-css-solutions-to-commons-fluid-layout-problems/

Answer (score 1):

`flexbox` can do that.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gg8yevm2/)

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
.fixed_width {
  width: 200px;
  background: #bada55;
}
.variable_width {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  background: plum;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="variable_width"></div>
  <div class="fixed_width"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Pepe Not in IE9 or earlier

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
width:100%;
}

.variable_width {
    max-width: 70%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:blue;
margin-right: -3px;
}
.fixed_width {
width:100px;
width: 28%;
display: inline-block;
    background-color:red;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

now you can use this code. i think it will work fine.you can add some content in variable width div class and check whether it is working or not.i have checked it and it really works :) .
http://jsfiddle.net/souraj/vaqbsdzk/

Comment: have you tried to reduce the content of the divs? i have checked and it works fine.left div has a variable width according to the content and the right div has a fixed width.

Comment: it is not according to the content, it is according to screen width. In either case the right div does not have a fixed width (you declared width:28%;}